# Create CSV from form, store on server and move to remote server

Tags: php, csv, ftp

I need to take data from a form and:

- create a csv file (this part is done and working)
- Upload to server (currently can only download)
- Move to a remote server using ftp_put

Here is what I have so far, creating the .csv which currently just downloads.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //collect form data
        $email      = $_POST['inf_field_Email'];
        //other form data
        //server side validation
        if($email=='') {
            $error[] = 'Email is required';
        }
        //create csv
        if(!isset($error)){
        $Content = "Email\n";
        //set the data of the CSV
        $Content .= "$email\n";
        # set the file name and create CSV file
        $FileName = "FormData_".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
        //this is where I can only create and download, I know the header is the issue here.
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
        echo $Content;
        exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

I am just trying to store on server. I am on an AWS S3 running Apache.

### Update

Per the advice below, I am now writing directly to a file on the server, however it is duplicating the header row with each submission.

```
<?php
    //same form data and validation as above
    if(!isset($error)){
    $Content = "Email\n";
    $Content .= "$email\n";

    # set the file name and create CSV file
    $fp = fopen("Registration.csv","a");
    $savestring = $Content;
    fwrite($fp,$savestring);
    fclose($fp);
    echo"<h1>Your Data has been saved</h1>";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can combine first 2 steps without including host machine.

1. Create csv file on the server rather than your proposed 2-step process.
2. Move file to whenever you need but if you are moving to remote server: make sure you are encrypting your data and using `https`.

Comment: Great advice, Im all for efficiency. How do I create file on server?

Comment: `file_put_contents` is one of the functions. You can find help and examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Also have a look at `str_getcsv` function for easier CSV creation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Thank you. Ive got a couple issues with duplicating the column headers but the info was a great start.